# Run php program from /var/www folder

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, command-line, xampp

I have lampp server and UBUNTU OS, when I use my command line I write,

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

for starting my xampp server on linux.
Now I can able to run my php code written in /opt/lampp/htdocs directly by calling,

```
localhost/myphpcode.php
```

And it works well.

But I want to run my php code from folder /var/www which is in root.
How can I run my php folder using this path?

Comment: no sir i want to run my code when i write it in /var/www/myphp.php and call in browser localhost/myphp.php.

Comment: Why don't you use the LAMP packages provided by Ubuntu?

Comment: Sir ,is there will any problem if i am using xampp for ubuntu?

Comment: Sir everything is working well when i call my code from /opt/lampp/htdocs but i want to know the process by which i can able to run my code from /var/www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit httpd.conf file and add `DocumentRoot "/var/www"` for modifying root directory, put your file there and restart server

Comment: Run "locate httpd.conf" to find httpd.conf

Comment: after changing when i restart apache and after that i am running my code it is given "You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. "

Comment: Give appropriate permission to /var/www using chmod

Comment: sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www

Comment: sir i already given that permission to that folder but after that it also giving same error.

Comment: There might be two DocumentRoot  field in httpd.conf change both fields

Comment: also when i run localhost now its also given same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49383/discussion-between-rahul-r-dhobi-and-swap-nil)

Comment: Thanks a lot rahul sir....now its working very well.Thanks for giving your attention to me.

Comment: add this line in httpd.conf <Directory "/var/www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory> after adding this my solutions makes perfect thanks again @Rahul sir.

Comment: If you think rahul sir this question is good then please vote up the question to become userful for others- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have Apache configured to serve PHP pages and that Apache config is setup correctly.

What happens when you hit localhost/file.php ? Does anything happen, or does it download the file?

Comment: Sir, when i hit on localhost/file.php where my file.php is placed in /var/www then it shows object not fount, And when my file.php is placed in /opt/lampp/htdocs then it working well, i only want to run my code from /var/www.

Comment: Sounds like your docroot isn't setup correctly for your site. Investigate .htaccess and ensure it is pointing to /var/www

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your php files in apache2 DocumentRoot i.e /var/www/html by default and start apache2 service provided it has php supported modules. You would be able to open the page on browser by localhost and also by ipaddress of the linux ubuntu box.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP -> This link would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker